# Converting code using linux regex.h to Visual studio <regex>

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010

So i have a bit of code that work on MacOSX and on win32 using the gnuWin32 regex library, the thing is it isn't compatible with 64bit builds.
I use regex in only a little bit of code, and i have to possibilities, I could find the 64bit version of the regex library for windows (which i couldn't find anywhere) or i could use the  library that visual studio uses.

I have NO IDEA at all how the VS regex library works, and I have a really bad time trying to find examples online.

Ultimately i would be happy with just a little tutorial which explains how it works.

This is the bit of code that uses regex, if someone had an idea about this how to convert it.

```
regex_t preg;
regcomp(&preg, "^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$", REG_NOSUB |  REG_EXTENDED);
bool isFloat = (regexec(&preg, str, 0, NULL, 0) == 0);
regfree(&preg);
return isFloat;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: let me provide you [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) of a standard C++ object

Comment: thant you, that'll help a lot. :)